# How to scale punjab bosh connection manager?

Tags: xmpp, load-balancing, openfire, punjab

How can I scale punjab connection manager?
server1 and server2 are behind loadbalancer. Not I first got connected with server1. It created the session on second request lets say I got connected with server2. server2 will not recognize my previous session and it will disconnect the request.
My openfire and Punjab server are in each EC2 box behind loadbalancer.

Answer (score 2):

You could add info to the HTTP header and use it for the load balancing when your balancer software supports this.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said you can use http headers to make sure you continue to go to the same node after a session is established. There is also a blog post I did some time ago about this issue. http://thetofu.livejournal.com/71339.html